# Selecionar determinados links BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x

Pessoal tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
def baixarhtml():
    page = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') 
    for links in soup.find_all(onclick=True):
        print (links)
baixarhtml()
```

saida;

```
<a href="#" onclick="abreProcessoPje('0016766-63.2018.5.16.0023')">[Andamentos] </a>
<a href="#" onclick="abreInteiroTeor('P','4981203', '')">[Inteiro Teor]
                    </a>
<a href="#" onclick="abreProcessoPje('0016788-64.2017.5.16.0021')">[Andamentos] </a>
<a href="#" onclick="abreInteiroTeor('P','5013921', '')">[Inteiro Teor]
                    </a>
<a href="#" onclick="abreProcessoPje('0102000-26.2012.5.16.0022')">[Andamentos] </a>
<a href="#" onclick="abreInteiroTeor('P','4964552', '')">[Inteiro Teor]
                    </a>
<a href="#" onclick="abreProcessoPje('0018161-44.2018.5.16.0006')">[Andamentos] </a>
<a href="#" onclick="abreInteiroTeor('P','4925986', '')">[Inteiro Teor]
                    </a>
<a href="#" onclick="abreProcessoPje('0018022-26.2017.5.16.0007')">[Andamentos] </a>
<a href="#" onclick="abreInteiroTeor('P','4964547', '')">[Inteiro Teor]
                    </a>
<a href="#" onclick="abreProcessoPje('0017480-44.2018.5.16.0016')">[Andamentos] </a>
```

como faço para pegar apenas os onclick="abreInteiroTeor"

Comment: funciona pra você usar algo como `filtrados = [link for link in links if ... ]` ?

Comment: Gustavo, meu comentário resolve seu problema? Você precisa que eu coloque o código completo com a condição que você tem que usar?

Comment: Agradeço se puder colocar o código.

Comment: ontem o stack inteiro ficou fora, não consegui postar antes. Veja se dá certo minha solução

Comment: Obrigado Flávio... logo farei o teste. Postarei o resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o seu código não é reprodutível eu não consigo testar, então me avise se der erro que eu corrijo, mas chuto que a solução seja algo assim

```
def baixarhtml():
    page = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') 
    links = soup.find_all(onclick=True)
    links = [link for link in links if 'abreInteiroTeor' in link['onclick']]
    print(links)

baixarhtml()
```

Comment: Desculpe pela demora, e informo que o codigo funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado Flavio.